# Choose selected nav items in slider tab and add class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I currently have a slider which auto slides and adds a class of ui-tabs-selected to each tab in the nav menu when it is active.

What I would like to to is add the selected class (ui-tabs-selected) to other elements which are not currently active. For example I have 5 nav tabs labelled 1 to 5, if 3 is active I would like 1 and 2 to have the ui-tabs-selected class. If 4 is selected I would like 1,2 and 3 to have the ui-tabs selected and so forth.

I have currently been testing it for just tabs 1 and 2 but can't seem to get it to work, i have added an if else addClass not-selected and this is returned even if #nav-fragment-2 has the class of ui-tabs-selected which shows there is something wrong within my code or I am doing things the complete wrong way :)

I have posted my code below, currently using the jQuery featured content slider with ui.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ui-tabs-nav").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
    if ( $('#nav-fragment-2').hasClass('ui-tabs-selected') ) {
$('#nav-fragment-1').addClass('.ui-tabs-selected');
} else {
$('#nav-fragment-1').addClass('no-selected');
}
});

</script>
```

**The nav menu:**

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
    <li class="nav-item tk-report" id="nav-fragment-1"><a href="#fragment-1"><img   src="{site_url}assets/images/main/how-1.png" width="28" height="28" alt="" /><span>1</span></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item tk-report" id="nav-fragment-2"><a href="#fragment-2"><img src="{site_url}assets/images/main/how-2.png" width="28" height="28" alt="" /><span>2</span></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item tk-report" id="nav-fragment-3"><a href="#fragment-3"><img src="{site_url}assets/images/main/how-3.png" width="28" height="28" alt="" /><span>3</span></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item tk-report" id="nav-fragment-4"><a href="#fragment-4"><img src="{site_url}assets/images/main/how-4.png" width="28" height="28" alt="" /><span>4</span></a></li>
    <li class="nav-item tk-report" id="nav-fragment-5"><a href="#fragment-5"><img src="{site_url}assets/images/main/how-4.png" width="28" height="28" alt="" /><span>5</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**EDIT:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ui-tabs-nav").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
$('.nav-item.tk-report.ui-tabs-selected').prevAll().addClass('.ui-tabs-selected');
});

</script>
```

Comment: Are you still having difficulties?

Answer (score 0):

Can be done with one line of code. Use the jQuery `prevAll` function:

```
$('.nav-item.tk-report.ui-tabs-selected').prevAll().addClass('ui-tabs-selected');
```

This code will select the element with those three classes:
`nav-item` + `tk-report` + `ui-tabs-selected` then traverse up to his siblings and add them the `ui-tabs-selected` class

`prevAll` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/):

> Description: Get all preceding siblings of each element in the set of
>   matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I see how you mean now. I have input the js into my code but still nothing happens, the selected tab still works fine but doesn't add the u-tabs-selected class to the previous tabs. I have edited my code above with my new js. Thanks

Comment: @Ben. I wrote `.` in the class name: `addClass('.ui-tabs-selected')` => `addClass('ui-tabs-selected')` I fixed it now. Hope it will do the trick

Comment: Hi gdoron. I have tried your suggestion only to get the same results :/. Not sure if its something to do with the jQuery ui class which is ui-tabs-selected. Would it be worth trying to create a different class with custom js and using that? If so any suggestions?

Comment: @Ben. I can't help you without seeing the problem, please give me a link to your site or a **JSFiddle** which is much better.